# “#1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date'” when trying to reset AI after backup

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I've restored my Wordpress database from an sql backup. However, in doing so, all of the tables have lost auto increment.

When I try to add it back in with this sql

```
ALTER TABLE `mercury_posts` CHANGE `ID` `ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I get the error `#1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date'`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Check the table definition for the post_date column

Comment: @juergend The broken table on my development server has an identical column definition to the working version on my production server. As far as I can tell, the only different between the two tables is the lack of AI on the ID column.

Comment: But the MySQL server settings may be different. It may be simpler to take another backup and restore it again.